# How do you escape dollar and braces, (i.e. ${title}) in a java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Ie how do you do this?

```
String string = "Sample string with ${title} to be inserted.";
string.replaceAll("${title}", title);
```

All of the following results in an error:

```
string.replaceAll("\\${title}", title);
string.replaceAll("\\\\${title}", title);
string.replaceAll("\\\\$\\{title\\}", title);
```

And more, nothing seems to work, it all results in an error like this:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 4 \\$\\{title\\}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2775)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1889)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure how the last one would result in an error; it'd just not match anything because you're using too many backslashes on the `$`.

This should work:

```
string.replaceAll("\\$\\{title\\}", title);
```

Answer (score 25):

the Pattern class has a escape function for uses like this

```
string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("${title}"), title);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could escape the search string as `\Q${title}\E`

Comment: +1 for showcasing a relatively unknown escape sequence in regexp

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical use case of template language such as FreeMarker.

Comment: I am not loading a templating language to replace one simple string. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

`\$\{title\}`

Comment: The back slashes will be escaped by Java not the Regex.

Comment: Then escape the back slashes: `\\$\\{title\\}`

Answer (score 0):

In Regular Expression the escape character is `\` to use this we have to write `\\` as in `String`, `\` is use as escape character.

For example `str = str.replaceAll("rot\\*speed", "rotorspeed");`

`rot*speed` will be replace with `rotorspeed`
.