# Using regex to split the words in String but not symbol

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Is it possible to use regex to split by words instead of symbol/special characters?

For instance, 
**It is fun, content=[I love java, content=[Java eclipse then split by content=[**

So the **results** will become like

It is fun

I love java

Java eclipse

I tried something like this but it have error that say HTTP Status 500 - illegal repetition near index

```
String [] strArray = testcontent.split("content=[");
                    for (String str :strArray) {
                    System.out.println("TestSplit" + str);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? What were the results?

Comment: Error, HTTP Status 500 - illegal repetition @AlexR

Comment: Your problem is to escape special characters, check my answer and let me know if works (I tested in Scala)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split accepts a regexp so you can use whatever expression you want, just be careful to escape special characters.

```
split("content\\=\\[")
```

or

```
 split(Pattern.quote("content=["))
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to play around with backslashes, `split(Pattern.quote("content=["))`, [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065932/1270789).

Comment: Thanks @KenY-N I didn't know that!!

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Sorry so how do I split SolrDocument{content=[? Is it something like this? split(" SolrDocument\ \{\ \content\ \=\ \[ ") @Carlos

Comment: Thank you so much too, just one more question. Is it possible to forward the String to JSP using getAttribute and printed out in JSP? @KenY-N

Comment: @Havealotofquestion I think you should read about regexp, when you want to check different patterns you can use |, for example split("content|SolrDocument").

Comment: Thank you will read more as I am new to this and java too. Hmm, one more question when I printed on the console it did show the split but why it only display one results when I forward the String to JSP using getAttribute method @CarlosVerdes

Comment: I think you should open another question for this ,) If you like my answer please mark as resolver :)